# Sending data from a class to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Its a Window Form Application where i have created a linked list.
one of my functions is a search function, it accepts an argument from the user and searches the linked list based on the input  and outputs everything in the Nod releated to it(Nod contains FirstName, LastName,Telephone) outputs it in a DataGridView on a form.

what iam not able to do: send the Nod related information( FirstName, LastName,Telephone) to the DataGridView on the form.

```
public void search(string input)
    {
        Node current = First;

        int txt;
        bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(input, out txt);

        if (!isNumerical)
        {

            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.FirstName.Equals(input) || current.LastName.Equals(input))
                {                       
                    Console.WriteLine(current.FirstName);
                    Console.WriteLine(current.LastName);
                    Console.WriteLine(current.Telephone);
                    Console.WriteLine("**********");
                }
                current = current.NextNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Telephone==txt)
                {                       
                    Console.WriteLine(current.FirstName);
                    Console.WriteLine(current.LastName);
                    Console.WriteLine(current.Telephone);
                    Console.WriteLine("**********");
                    break;
                }
                current = current.NextNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem? why can't you send the info? Does your search find the needed results? Were is your search method located ( in the class file where DataGridView is located, or in your custom list )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i guessed your structure right.

On a form you have a DataGridView, in the code-behind of this form you call search.

If there will be only single result, then use Grant Winney suggestion. But i think there might be many results, then:

```
public List<Node> search(string input)
```

In the method create a List results and init it.

Then when result is found add it to the list.

In the end of the method add:

```
return results;
```

Use this method as:

```
var results = search(string input);
```

or
    List

And after using the method loop the list and populate your DataGridView

**Addition:**

Check your WHILEs

First loop doesn;t end when you find a first match, but second does.

Comment: i really must thank you, didn't think of doing it like that, tried it and it works.